# Magento 2 Cron runs for an hour on Kubernetes

Tags: magento2

When running Magento crons on Kubernetes (or even Docker), the cron never ends.
Running `magento cron:run` every minute, but it takes an hour. And there is no error.
What could be the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because the cron was starting the queue consumers and they are configured to run with 10000 --max-messages by default (Magento documentation says 1000).

When the cron runs it adds a bunch of background processes for the queue consumers:

```
$ kubectl exec -n my-store magento-75788af261-adwdc -c magento ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  18048  1932 ?        Ss   14:13   0:00 /bin/bash /setup.sh
root        16  0.0  0.0   4284   588 ?        S    14:13   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND
root        18  0.0  0.0 274652 19168 ?        S    14:13   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data    20  0.9  0.2 344228 90216 ?        S    14:13   1:50 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data    24  0.9  0.2 344232 86344 ?        S    14:13   1:41 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data    59  0.0  0.2 291524 94128 ?        S    14:15   0:03 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start commonErrorManagement --pid-file-path=commonErrorManagement-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    61  0.0  0.2 291524 94024 ?        S    14:15   0:03 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start ping --pid-file-path=ping-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    63  0.0  0.3 317288 118348 ?       S    14:15   0:05 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start productConsumer --pid-file-path=productConsumer-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    65  0.0  0.2 293740 95408 ?        S    14:15   0:03 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start stockConsumer --pid-file-path=stockConsumer-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    67  0.0  0.2 293752 95652 ?        S    14:15   0:03 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start productReturnUpdatedConsumer --pid-file-path=productReturnUpdatedConsumer-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    69  0.0  0.3 293704 97224 ?        S    14:15   0:03 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start refundUpdatedConsumer --pid-file-path=refundUpdatedConsumer-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    71  0.0  0.3 317288 118240 ?       S    14:15   0:04 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start orderCancellation --pid-file-path=orderCancellation-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    73  0.0  0.3 317288 118116 ?       S    14:15   0:04 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start orderGetNotifications --pid-file-path=orderGetNotifications-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    75  0.0  0.3 317288 118440 ?       S    14:15   0:04 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start orderResendNotification --pid-file-path=orderResendNotification-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    77  0.0  0.3 317292 118508 ?       S    14:15   0:04 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start orderConsumer --pid-file-path=orderConsumer-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    79  0.0  0.2 291524 93944 ?        S    14:15   0:03 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start orderUpdatedConsumer --pid-file-path=orderUpdatedConsumer-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    82  0.0  0.3 295756 97992 ?        S    14:15   0:03 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start customerShipmentDoneConsumer --pid-file-path=customerShipmentDoneConsumer-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    84  0.0  0.2 291656 93784 ?        S    14:15   0:03 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start orderLineCancelledConsumer --pid-file-path=orderLineCancelledConsumer-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    86  0.0  0.2 291656 94968 ?        S    14:15   0:03 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start shippingAddressUpdated --pid-file-path=shippingAddressUpdated-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    92  0.0  0.3 317292 119656 ?       S    14:15   0:04 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start serviceBusDiscover --pid-file-path=serviceBusDiscover-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data    94  0.0  0.3 317292 118524 ?       S    14:15   0:04 /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start async.operations.all --pid-file-path=async.operations.all-magento76799dc865rglqw.pid --max-messages=10000
www-data   178  1.6  0.2 336144 81796 ?        S    16:24   0:53 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data   179  1.2  0.2 336220 83776 ?        S    16:24   0:42 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data   195  1.3  0.2 336160 81964 ?        S    16:27   0:42 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data   198  1.0  0.2 333196 74692 ?        S    16:30   0:31 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data   199  1.0  0.2 333196 74696 ?        S    16:30   0:31 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data   200  1.0  0.2 333212 74708 ?        S    16:30   0:29 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data   201  1.3  0.2 333140 74632 ?        S    16:30   0:40 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
www-data   210  1.1  0.2 333140 74636 ?        S    16:30   0:34 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
root       440  0.0  0.0  36640  2712 ?        Rs   17:19   0:00 ps aux
```

And Kubernetes will just kill the cron pod when the timeout is hit (1 hour by default).
An easy fix is running the consumers on Supervisord and run Supervisord on its own pod. Also make sure to disable the queue consumers from running on cron by adding to the env.php:

```
...
    'cron_consumers_runner' => array(
        'cron_run' => false
    ),
...
```

I added all details on this post: https://magebr.com/running-crons-queue-kubernetes